# AND not working with other query fields in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm new in Loopback so may be it sound silly. Here is my query

```
const treats = await treatDetails.find({
  where: {
    and: someArray,
    endDate: { gt: someDate },
  },
```

`someArray` is an array on which i want to apply `AND` operation and outside of that and i want to get records with `endDate` greater than `someDate`

Comment: Give sample example for `someArray `

Answer (score 3):

You can use `and` with `array of json object`.

> Also you can add `endDate: { gt: someDate }` in `and`

```
let cond = [{ id: "id" }, { 'image': "url" }];

cons.push({ endDate: { gt: someDate } });

Model.find({ where: { and: cond } });
```